# Grails 3 java time form binding

Tags: grails

How can I bind domain class fields of type `LocalDateTime` or `LocalDate` to form inputs in Grails 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grails-java8 plugin makes that work

https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-java8

Note you also need the hibernate-java8 dependency as well

Comment: I've tried your plugin beforehand, but hibernate dependency wasn't mentioned anywhere. I'm building a form with Grails Fields plugin, but even if I declare `f:field` of a `LocalDateTime` property of the bean explicitly, I still get no success. Could you provide some more info?

Comment: File an issue on the grails-java8 plugin github repo

Answer (score 1):

adding this to the dependencies in the `build.gradle` file:

```
compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-java8:5.1.3.Final"
```

should allow you to have a domain like this:

```
class Test {

     LocalDateTime start
     Duration duration
}
```

Creating an object:

```
new Test(start: LocalDateTime.of(2017,1,1,8,0,0), duration: Duration.ofHours(5)).save()
```

will look like this in the database:

```
+----+---------+----------------+---------------------+
| id | version | duration       | start               |
+----+---------+----------------+---------------------+
|  1 |       0 | 18000000000000 | 2017-01-01 08:00:00 |
+----+---------+----------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: I am looking for a solution that would allow me to use form parameters binding so LocalDateTime and others could be converted to string and vice versa, not DB stuff

Comment: Sorry, I don't use grails for that I use vaadin. Vaadin 8 binds with LocalDate and LocalDateTime.